# Is this a decent set of IPTables rules?

Tags: ubuntu, security, iptables

Can anyone please point out to me whether, assuming that the needs for a given (Ubuntu 12.04) server are only SSH, NTP (client), HTTP(S) and system updates (`apt-get` or `aptitude`), the following set of rules is a decent one? My idea is to drop all traffic by default and open only the necessary ports on the necessary states and interfaces...

```
*filter

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Defaults
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-P INPUT   DROP
-P OUTPUT  DROP
-P FORWARD DROP

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Loopback
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-A INPUT  -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# SSH
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-A INPUT  -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED     -j ACCEPT

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# NTP
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-A INPUT  -i eth0 -p udp --sport 123 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED     -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DNS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-A INPUT  -i eth0 -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED     -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Updates
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-A INPUT  -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 80  --dport 32768:61000 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED     -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80  --sport 32768:61000 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT  -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 --dport 32768:61000 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED     -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 --sport 32768:61000 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Logging
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-A INPUT -m limit --limit 125/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES DENIED " --log-level 7

COMMIT
```

Am I overlooking something? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that with this ruleset you are also restricting outbound traffic to specific ports only. You could run into problems because of this at some point (e.g. cloning a git repository). You may want to remove the `-A OUTPUT` rules and instead add the following before `COMMIT`:

```
## Allow inbound established and related outside communication
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

## Allow initiating outbound communications
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You may also want to allow ICMP traffic (ping etc):

```
## Allow ICMP traffic
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Finally the following will drop packets from outsiders sending packets as localhost (add before the loopback rules):

```
## Drop outside packets with localhost address - anti-spoofing measure
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 -i ! lo -j DROP
```